# How to parse JSON object, if one of it's key has strigified value

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, parsing

On the following, the key `c` has a stringified value:

```
let obj = {
   a: "apple",
   b: 2,
   c: '{"p":"11","q":"22","r":{"x":"aa","y":"bb"}}'
   d: "3"
}
```

I need to parse this object. I may have multiple keys with stringified object data and some plain strings.

I tried by doing `JSON.parse(obj)` but it's giving an error. I also tried with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` but it returns the same result as the intial `obj`.

Is there any possible way to solve this case?

Comment: `obj` is not JSON which is why it will not parse. `obj.c` has a value which is a valid JSON string

Comment: Maybe you want `obj.c = JSON.parse(obj.c)`.  That will replace the JSON (string) with the JavaScript Object it represents.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over each entry of the object and use `JSON.parse` on each string value.

```js
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: '{"p":"11","q":"22","r":{"x":"aa","y":"bb"}}' }
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj))
  if (typeof val === 'string') obj[key] = JSON.parse(val);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Sorry to mention I have edited the question (example provided). This solution won't work if we have plain strings as values.

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaBethu Then, how do you know which keys you actually want to parse? (You could always just catch the exception from `JSON.parse`.)

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaBethu This works for your new example: https://jsfiddle.net/g9cu1ave/

Comment: Beware, if one of the properties of `obj` were something like `a: "hello"`, this code would fail to parse `hello` as JSON.  I think the original asker should specify a more robust way to know which property values are JSON and which are not.  Perhaps replacing all strings that are JSON is reasonable, but maybe then catching the exception from values that fail to parse might be prudent.

Comment: @Wyck Yes, I showed an example of that in the previous comment.

Comment: If we have string of numerics, then JSON.parse will convert it into numbers. 
eg: a: "1" => JSON.parse("1") is 1, which will change the value of a: 1.

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaBethu So how do you want to determine which keys should actually be parsed? You need to have specific criteria.

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaBethu  Fix your question to specify what you want!  The string `1` is valid JSON.

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaBethu That is not specific criteria on which values to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON.

[`obj` isn't JSON](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). It's a JavaScript object.

`obj.c` is a string of JSON. You can parse that.

```
const result = JSON.parse(obj.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all property values that successfully parses as JSON with the resulting object.  It uses an exception handler to catch the cases where the string is not valid JSON.

```js
let obj = {
   a: "apple",
   b: 2,
   c: '{"p":"11","q":"22","r":{"x":"aa","y":"bb"}}',
   d: "3"
}

for (let key in obj) {
  try {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string' && obj[key].startsWith('{')) {
      obj[key] = JSON.parse(obj[key]);
    }
  }
  catch (ignore) {}
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: But this will replace string of numerics with numeric values. 
Like a: "1"  => JSON.parse("1") is 1
So a: 1 value get's changed.

Comment: Yes, because that's valid JSON.  You'll have to specify what you want converted from JSON and what you don't in a more specific way then.  How do **you** want to specify which values are to be parsed and which ones aren't?  (This is also the reason for my downvote for your question, which is now going to be a close vote.)

Comment: I'm not a mind reader, but you can conditionally replace only values that are strings that start with `{` if that's how you want to discriminate `1` from `{"p":"11"}`.

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaBethu I changed my answer to address your comment.  Are you happy with it now?